# Do certain MSTest DataSource providers perform better than others?

Tags: unit-testing, datasource, mstest, data-driven-tests

The MSTest **DataSourceAttribute** supports different data providers for data driven tests (*CSV, Excel, SQL, XML, MTM*, etc). I'm trying to determine if one is markedly faster or if they all have comparable performance. The MS documentation doesn't seem to address this. I suppose I could profile the different providers but thought I would ask first in case someone had experience with this.